# How to space-efficiently store and retrieve std::vector<int> values in a file

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I have a `std::vector<int>` which is made of up values -1,0,1. After some initial manipulation on these values I end up with a vector in which the -1 values can be omitted. 
How do i store the needed 0,1 values in a file in an efficient way both space (more important) and time.

It seems there are 3 recommended options `std::vector<bool>`, `std::bitset` and `boost::dynamic_bitset`but which will be the best in this case.
I can loop through the vector and `if value!=-1` add it to a `vector<bool>` and then store it, but is it the best way? The vector has around 1 million elements (after manipulation).

```
// Initialize temp_array of size n(obtained in runtime) with value -1
std::vector<int> temp_array(n, -1);
// Do some manipulation on the temp array
// Now temp array has values containing -1,0,1 of which all occurrences of -1 can be removed without worrying about the index
std::vector<bool>final_array;
for (const auto &i : temp_array)
    {
      if (i != -1)
      {
        final_array.push_back(i);
      }
    }
// How to store and retrieve this in the most space efficient way
```

Edit:
Some more background detail on the problem. Space efficiency is a must because i'm storing a compressed format of an adjacency matrix (performing some custom compression). Each node can have upto a million edges(sometimes even more) and there are around 10 million such nodes (dealing with large graphs). The aim is to load up a compressed form of this graph fully in memory and support basic querying without having o decompress and support streaming edge (For example the live journal graph has 4,847,571 nodes).

Comment: I would suggest starting with the erase-remove idiom and profile from their to see if it is acceptable.  This lets you avoid creating another buffer and, after erasure, you can just about whats left in the vector to the file.

Comment: Most efficient in time is to write and read the raw binary contents. Most efficient in space is to write a bitmap, where each bit is a single element in the vector. If you pick one you can't have the other.

Comment: Bit pack a bunch of unsigned char datatypes with the bits using Num=Num|(1<<BitNum); when you get to the end of the 8 bits, push that char into an array, and move to the next 8 bits, repeat until you're done. Write the entire binary array of chars as a single binary write. That's how I'd do it anyway. You would be advised to specify the number of elements at the start of the file, otherwise you'll have no way of knowing where in the byte the final bit stops. And that could get ugly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If its a choice between the two, then space efficiency is the most important.

Comment: Then perhaps a [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) might be better than `std::vector<bool>`?

Comment: I would ask do you really need to be efficient on space when saving to a file? 1 million values is not a lot when thinking in terms of off-line storage. Binary will give you the most efficient storage and probably retrial times but is also the hardest to debug.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ```std::bitset``` requires the N to be known which i get to know only during run time. Even if i store it in the ```std::bitset``` format it seems there is no space efficient method to store it in a file. The 3 supported methods ```to_string``` : Stores each bit as a byte taking 8x space, while my data wont fit into a single ```to_ulong``` or ```to_ullong```.

Comment: @MartinYork Yep space efficiency is important. The problem is not with the 1 million values its with the 10 million more such values.

Comment: ***Why*** is space so critical? Where are you saving this data? It can't be on a modern multi-terabyte disk. Even on a moderately sized USB stick such a file saved using plain 4-byte `int` for each value would be just a fraction of the usable space. Please edit your question to include the use-case, the *actual* and *real* problem you need to solve, and *why* you need to save it as space-efficiently as possible.

Comment: How about using a compression library (say zlib for instance)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have added some more information to the original question. Hope this gives a better view of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If space efficiency is a big issue and all you have are 0s and 1s then you could consider storing a run-length encoding of your binary string.

Please see, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding

Worst case is when you have alternating 0s and 1s.

Code should be relatively straightforward involving a single pass over vector.

Comment: I haven't benchmarked Run Length encoding yet but from what i can see in my data there are no considerable runs of 0's and 1's in my data. So run length encoding may not be so efficient on the data.

Comment: If your binary data is close to a random distribution of 0s and 1s then you can't really get much compression. Based on your updated question, you are looking for data compaction not necessarily compression. Look for design details of in memory graph databases. That should lead you to good ideas.